# multiple 'res' statements in express causing problems?

Tags: express, redirect, response

I am writing a Node.js application and I am constantly having problems with "res" statements...it seems using more than one will throw an error.  For example in the following example:

```
//POST /login gets urlencoded bodies
app.post('/login', urlencodedParser, csrfProtection, function (req, res) {     
 if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400)

    console.log("Posted data:" + JSON.stringify(req.body));
    console.log("req.body.pword:" + req.body.pword);
    console.log("req.body.usr:" + req.body.usr);

 if (loggedIn == true) {
    res.send("Already logged in.");
 }
 else {

    if (req.body.pword == password) {
        loggedIn = true;
    //res.send('welcome, ' + req.body.usr)
        console.log("Logged in");

        res.redirect('/admin');

      }
     }

    })
```

As written, the "res.redirect" will work fine as intended.  However if I "uncomment" the line that reads "res.send('welcome, ' + req.body.usr)" an error will be thrown and the redirect does not execute.  Errors such as these seem to happen constantly when attempting to use multiple "res" statements.  Can anybody enlighten me as to what is happening that I obviously don't understand...as well as a possible work-around?  I thank you in advance.  Regards.

Answer (score 0):

`res.redirect` doesn't make sense to use with `res.send` - they both terminate the response, and with a redirect, the user will never see the text you are sending. Use one or the other, not both.

Comment: thank you for your reply.  If "res" terminates the response, how can I prevent the termination...?  Is there a "reset" of some sort...?  Or alternatively how can I send a simple informative message (such as "welcome + req.body.usr" in my example) without usage of "res"...is there another command that is better to use for such needs?  Thanks again.

Comment: You can include the welcome message as part of the `/admin` page - maybe do the redirect to `/admin?welcome=true` when the user logs in, and show the message if `welcome` is `true`.

Comment: For your other questions, I'd recommend reading a tutorial about how the HTTP protocol works, and learning how to read raw request and response output using `curl` or a similar tool.

Comment: OK thank you again...I gather from your response there is no other way to do it...hahaha.  I guess what you are saying there is only 1 request and 1 response for any HTTP request, and no way around that...other than by usage of another tool such as "curl" you mention or something else...correct?   Regards

Comment: That's right, one request has one response. curl or any other tool does not change this, but it will help you to understand the structure better. You should be able to tell what requests and responses will be sent as a result of using your app code.

Comment: OK thank you for your time in explaining that to me ...I appreciate it.  At least that explains why I constantly have errors being thrown when I'm using more than one "res" statement.  Regards.